# Import users into Firebase with password encrypted with MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, firebase-authentication, cryptography, md5

I'm trying to import my existing database of users into Firebase with the password encrypted using `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`. I cant seem to get it functional, at least with the Firebase Admin SDK in C#.

The error it gives me is cannot implicity convert system.Security.Cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider to firebase_admin.auth.user import hash

Here is my code:

```
        try
        {
            string password = "hashed_password";
            var users = new List<ImportUserRecordArgs>()
{
    new ImportUserRecordArgs()
    {
        Uid = "some-uid",
        Email = "user@example.com",
        PasswordHash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password),
        PasswordSalt = null,
    },
};

            var options = new UserImportOptions()
            {
                Hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
                {
                    //Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text))
                },
            };

            UserImportResult result = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.ImportUsersAsync(users, options);
            foreach (ErrorInfo indexedError in result.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to import user: {indexedError.Reason}");
            }
        }
        catch (FirebaseAuthException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error importing users: {e.Message}");
        }
```

My question is, how should I configure `UserImportedOptions` so it works...

I'm using C# for this.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it was just a matter of using

```
      var options = new UserImportOptions()
            {
                Hash = new Md5
                {
                    Rounds = 0
                },
            };
```